# How to give border radius to map in react native?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

> MapView inside a container view

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <MapView style={[styles.map]}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 18.978189,
      longitude: 73.024911,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

> To give curved border to my map i gave borderRadius to the container view

```
const styles = {
 container:{
   marginTop:20,
   borderWidth:1,
   borderRadius:20
 },
 map:{
   height:200,
 },
}
```

> This gave border to my view and my view is actually getting the borderRadius, i cross checked it by giving borderWidth:1. But my map is not getting this border of container. Maps corner get out of the container views border. What should i do to give borderRadius to my map.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198

Answer (score 28):

You can set

```
overflow: 'hidden'
```

in your container. It should hide the overflow of the mapView.

Comment: Adding overflow also doesnt work. view is not clipped by the parent's borderRadius even if the parent has overflow: 'hidden' enabled. The corners of the map is still visible outside of the rounded corners

Comment: any answer to this?  I'm seeing similar things still

Comment: you really are the king of kings

Answer (score 4):

With some tinkering figured out the following

```
            <View style={{ 
                height: moderateScale(300) - 60, 
                zIndex: -1, 
                borderRadius: 10, 
                borderWidth: 1, 
                borderColor: userInterface.buttonSelectedFill, 
                overflow: 'hidden',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                <MapView 
                    style={{flex: 1, height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 10, }} 
                    //ref={ map => {currentMap = map }}
                    //region={props.region}
                    rotateEnabled={false}
                    loadingEnabled={true}
                ></MapView>                
            </View>
```

The `overflow: 'hidden'` did not work until I also made the parent `alignItems: 'center'` and 'justifyContent: 'center'`

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it inside a parent view with **borderRadius** and **hiding overflow** did the trick!

```html
<View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', top: 30, width: '75%', height: 200, borderRadius: 10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  <MapView
    style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
    scrollEnabled={true}
    Region={{ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }}
    customMapStyle={mapStyle}
  >
    <Marker
      coordinate={{ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02 }}
      pinColor={"white"}
      title={"You are here"}
    />
  </MapView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView
          region={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
         
        </MapView>
 </View>
```

**The style  of the container is below**

```
mapContainer:{
    width: responsiveWidth(95),
    height: responsiveHeight(25),
    borderRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
    overflow: 'hidden',
  
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the below code with `MapView & Marker`
which is Wrapped inside the `parent view with borderRadius and hiding overflow`,

```
<View style={{ width: "95%", borderRadius: moderatescale(20),borderWidth:moderatescale(2),borderColor:'#fff',  backgroundColor: '#fff', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center',overflow: 'hidden', shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)', shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2, }, shadowOpacity: 0.25, shadowRadius: 3.84, elevation: 5, }}>

<MapView
    ref={mapView}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: verticalscale(150)}}
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: 25.276987,
        longitude: 55.296249,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0111,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0111,
    }}
>

    <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{ latitude: 25.276987, longitude: 55.296249, }}
        title={"My Location"}
        image={require("your marker image")}
        style={{ width: moderatescale(20), height: verticalscale(20) }}
    >
        
    </MapView.Marker>

</MapView>
</View>
```